# Why is CSS not changing my updates in localhost and VScode (Windows 10)

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, localhost

Here is my `<head>` code for CSS

```
    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/jwcodeme/style/main-style.css" />
```

I have tried

```
    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jwcodeme/style/main-style.css" />
```

but it just shows the previous version and I have even related restarted Localhost restarted my browser restarted VScode and rebooted my PC and I have saved all my work twice and even triple times. But it still has not updated my HTML page!

If it is a directory tree problem here are the paths.

-assets

- Ban_1_bg.jpg
- Logo.png

-javascript

- main-script.js

-pages

- contact.html
- index.html

-style

- main-style.css

-README.txt

Comment: Missing quote in `href`: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=/jwcodeme/style/main-style.css" />`

Comment: Oh I have tried it with the quote it does not work!

Comment: Where does `jwcodeme` fit in your directory tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a cache issue, so try clearing it first. If that doesn't work then you can try to change the name of the css file to force the browser to read the new file. And if all else fails then you could ask for a different version of your file.

Ex: styles.css?v=1

```html
<!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jwcodeme/style/main-style.css?v=1" />
```